# Cordova electron is not packaging the dependencies

Tags: node.js, cordova, electron, cordova-plugins, electron-packager

I'm currently working on a Cordova Angular application that utilizes the Electron platform. As part of the project, I've integrated a library named "event-pubsub.". The installed library is in node_modules folder.

In a separate project dedicated to the Cordova Electron plugin, named "tcp-plugin," I'm employing the following code:

```
var Events = self.require('event-pubsub');
```

To include this plugin in the Cordova Angular project, I executed the command:

```
cordova plugin add tcp-plugin
```

Building the project with `ng build` proceeds without any issues, and I can successfully build the Electron app using:

```
cordova build electron
```

However, upon running the packaged Electron app, I encounter a plugin-related error:

```
Module not found: event-pubsub
```

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.